# C#.NET Generating web service reference using WSDL (from XML schema) problem

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, web-services

I am using VS2010 and using the "add service reference" feature, to generate client classes from my WSDL. I am having a problem with one of my elements, which is defined in the WSDL as follows:

```
<xs:simpleType name="NumberType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="ONE" /> 
        <xs:enumeration value="TWO" /> 
        <xs:enumeration value="THREE" /> 
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This type is used in one of my elements like this:

```
<xs:element name="NumberTypes">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:list itemType="tns:NumberType" /> 
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

The problem is that VS is converting this particular element to a string type, when it should be an enumeration. so it converts it to a string NumberTypes which has a get method returning numberTypesField also of type string.

I think the problem is related to the fact that my schema NumberTypes element uses the xs:list, with 'itemType' attribute. if I change this to xs:element with type="tns:NumberType" attribute instead then the enumeration is generated as it should be.

So how can I make the enumeration work with xs:list? Why is it not converting correctly in the first place?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: ah ah!, the big lie of interoperability and standards. I loose some hair with making java speak to .Net. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had much luck getting xs:list to serialize properly.  Instead, I just allow for multiple instances of the same node, and .NET knows how to put it into a "list" or "array" properly.

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="NumberTypes">
    ...
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that works :) hmm it now generates the enum correctly (NumberType)  and also generates a NumberTypes element which has the type NumberType[]  ...  array is a bit hard to work with - is it possible to make .NET generate a list instead? otherwise I have to resize the array to add to it, or initialise it to the size of the enum even though there may not be that many elements. Is there a better way?

Comment: it's not working though - no matter what I select in the collections type dropdown (arraylist, generic list etc) it always continues to generate arrays. any ideas what's wrong? the generated code looks like this always:         
/// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("NumberTypes", Order=0)]
        public NumberType[] NumberTypes {
            get {
                return this.numberTypesField;
            }
            set {
                this.numberTypesField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("NumberTypes");
            }
        }

Comment: well apparently it's because my schema requires XMLSerializer instead of DataContractSerializer (which can generate lists). so does this mean I have to work with arrays? :s

Comment: It seems like arrays are what .NET wants you to use, although there are some tricks based on how you are using the serialized objects.  This article helps to clarify: http://raypendergraph.wikidot.com/article:basic-cs-xml-serialization
See the "To-Many" relationships section.