# Forbidden XML Schema constructs in WSDL of a web service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, xsd

I am a Java developer who has created a rather big Web service that works nice with Java clients or other tools (Soap UI).

One of our clients wants to write a .NET client for the web service and uses the "add service reference" feature of VS2010. According to the client this does not work since our WSDL and XSD files use "Forbidden XML constructs" as defined in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sonuarora/archive/2007/06/16/contract-generation-from-wsdl-xml-schema-datacontractserializer-vs-xmlserializer.aspx):

The problem is that we have made heavy usage of xsd:attribute data in WSDL.

So the question is: 
Is there a workaround to make .NET stub generation code compliant with WSDL/XSD files that contain xsd:attribute? Is there another .NET library for webservices that supports this feature?

Another question of mine would be why does Microsoft impose these limitations in the first place? Why xsd:attribute is a forbidden costruct in a web service??? Any clues on that?

Probably related: [C#.NET Generating web service reference using WSDL (from XML schema) problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000474/c-net-generating-web-service-reference-using-wsdl-from-xml-schema-problem)

Comment: There are always going to be certain schema constructs that cannot be translated to stub code. Developers can still consume your web service with manually constructed messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is that you should **NOT** use the modern way of generating stubs with [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) and instead use the legacy way with [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Creating stubs from the command line with wsdl.exe works fine. The resulting code works as expected and the .NET client connects to the Axis2 Web service.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a machine with the [.NET Framework](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=186916) on it why don't you use svcutil to generate a proxy/config settings for him and send it to him?

See [www.svcutil.com](http://www.svcutil.com/) for the list of switches and options that are available to you

I have found that if the customer cannot do it one way and you provide a documented (possibly automated) way of doing things then that will generally suffice.

Comment: Tried svcutil and it does not work either but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the HelloWorld.wsdl supplied in the link with the .NET version of Remobjects (http://www.remobjects.com) and it seemed to work fine. I don't have an actual service to test this with but I would suggest that you (or the client :) ) download it and give it a try.

The .NET version can be found here:

http://www.remobjects.com/ro/net.aspx